# List of all Visual Studio compiler errors and warnings, with their numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to disable a specific kind of warning but I'm having trouble finding its warning number so that I can blacklist it to the depths of hell in the project settings. This particular warning isn't showing up in any console output (only in the Error List UI), so it isn't revealing its number.

Does anyone have a list of all compiler errors and warnings along with their numbers?

Regardless of whether I just haven't looked well enough for either the specific warning number or a list, my faith in humanity suffered some damage when I couldn't find such a list on the internet. So I think an exhaustive list would be useful.

Comment: A list of all compiler errors and warnings? What makes you think there'd be a single list? There have been *many* versions of visual studio and the C# compiler, and things change over time. Rather than hunting for these list(s), why not stop being cryptic and give us the actual text that you have? We may be able to find information on that *specific* warning (or may be able to point you to e.g. the fact that it may not *be* a compiler warning)

Comment: Something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx (found by googling "C# compiler errors")?

Comment: I didn't know error/warning numbers would have different meanings. @WillemvanRumpt That documentation is indexed by the error/warning number, meaning you need to know the number first. I would like a single exhaustive list. Worst case I'll hack a script to extract such a list, but it seem weird to me that there isn't one out there.

Comment: amr mentioned the error number is not shown.  @amr it would be quite useful if you also post the exact text of the warning/error you want to disable. Especially as the "no error number shown" is not very common (for warnings its possible, for errors it shouldnt be the case)

Comment: @Thomas i'm not posting the specific warning/error because it's irrelevant to this question (i anticipate needing this list in the future for other warnings)

Comment: "my faith in humanity suffered some damage when I couldn't find such a list on the interne" for this: From my experience it is mostly about the correct keywords.....with those being sometimes QUITE counterintuitive to what you are searching for.

Comment: @amr: Then you have a problem at hands as like I said many warnings don't have a number (at least when I look at the warnings error list in the project I'm currently working on I see a number just for ordering purposes but NO warning number. I'm not sure if there are ANY numbers/codes for warnings at all (and in some cases its slight differences in wording that change the whole meaning of the warning)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to generate a single table of all the C# error codes and their respective message (e.g. for reference purposes), you can use [this](https://sites.google.com/site/softwareabnet/Home/csharp/CsharpErrorMsgs) useful script, which parses the MSDN list and compiles a HTML table (could use some styling though).

Comment: Thank you. In keeping with my oath I actually did write a script and was almost done (just needed to fix some edge cases) but I lost it. Whoops.

Comment: It saves as a text file and should be renamed to .html, as an fyi.  Excellent link, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The list on MSDN is incomplete. I made a small program to generate the [full list](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/GenerateCSharpErrors/blob/master/CSharpErrorsAndWarnings.md) from the Roslyn source code.

Comment: This is a nice list, but it certainly isn't the "full" list. For example, I'm not finding the "No XML encryptor configured." warning. This: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/ed303a13b4202b782b8b8638a4fc56187afa8cf0/src/aspnetcore/src/DataProtection/DataProtection/src/LoggingExtensions.cs#L142

Really just need to know what its ID is so I can suppress it... and `35` isn't it... specifically `<NoWarn>35</NoWarn>` didn't suppress it. Is your list outdated? Can you regenerate it?

Comment: @SerjSagan you're confusing compilation errors and runtime errors.
The page I linked to only lists the compilation errors and warnings. It might be slightly outdated, but regenerating it won't add the error you mentioned...
`<NoWarn>` only applies to compilation warnings and has no effect on the runtime behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find a list of [error codes for VS 2013 under MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228296.aspx).

If you need a list for a different version of Visual Studio, there is a link "Other Versions" at the top of the page.

Note that these are organized by number, so you'll still have to search through them to find the specific error you're looking for.